# How to read a BeautifulSoup Div Tag object as a dictionary

Tags: python, html, dictionary, beautifulsoup, tags

New to HTML and BeautifulSoup here, so appologies . . .
I read a Real Estate website with BS4 and managed to get the info I want in a particular Div Class

```
list_1_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit")
```

BS4 finds 29 Parent Divs, each containing many child Divs, but all the info I want seems to be in the parent, so I removed all their children Divs.  The resulting parent Div in the variable "*s_row*" looks like a string when I print it, but Debug Mode describes "*s_row*" as **{Tag: 3} containing attrs = {dict: 13}** and then lists the elements I want in a nice structured list in the Debug window.

How do I print (or pass to Pandas) the underlying Dictionary inside the {Tag} object?  My eventual goal is to have a table of the 13 dictionary elements as columns, with 29 rows containing the values from each "*s_row*".  Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wiki = "https://www.lamudi.com.ph/metro-manila/makati/rockwell-1/buy/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features='html.parser')
list_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit")
for s_row in list_divs:
    for child in s_row.find_all("div"):
        child.decompose()
    print(s_row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you want to extract every attribute as column in dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


wiki = "https://www.lamudi.com.ph/metro-manila/makati/rockwell-1/buy/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features='html.parser')
list_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit")
all_data = []
for s_row in list_divs:
    all_data.append({})
    for a in s_row.attrs:
        if a == 'class':
            continue
        all_data[-1][a] = s_row[a]

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   data-price data-category                data-subcategories data-car_spaces data-bedrooms  ... data-price_range data-sqm_range data-rooms_total data-land_size data-subdivisionname
0    82000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]               2             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
1     9800000   condominium          ["condominium","studio"]             NaN             1  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
2    48990000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]             NaN             2  ...      37.8M-48.9M     93-121 sqm              NaN            NaN                  NaN
3    73730000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]             NaN             3  ...      45.3M-73.7M    126-202 sqm              NaN            NaN                  NaN
4    26600000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]             NaN             1  ...            26.6M         62 sqm              NaN            NaN                  NaN
5    27500000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               1             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
6   130000000   condominium     ["condominium","penthouse-1"]             NaN             4  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
7    78000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]               2             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
8    55000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]               2             3  ...              NaN            165                3            NaN                  NaN
9    19000000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]               1             1  ...              NaN             64                1            NaN                  NaN
10   30000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]             NaN             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
11   14000000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]             NaN             1  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
12   50000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]             NaN             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
13   48000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]             NaN             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
14   27000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]             NaN             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
15   36000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]             NaN             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
16   52000000         house   ["house","single-family-house"]               4             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            110         Palm Village
17   48000000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]               2             3  ...              NaN            NaN                4            NaN                  NaN
18   37500000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               2             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
19   19000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               1             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
20   66700000   condominium       ["condominium","3-bedroom"]               2             3  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
21   16500000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               1             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
22   12900000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]               1             1  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
23   20000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               1             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
24   17300000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]             NaN             1  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
25   25000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]             NaN             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
26   14000000   condominium  ["condominium","single-bedroom"]             NaN             1  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
27   32000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]             NaN             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN
28   38000000   condominium  ["condominium","double-bedroom"]               1             2  ...              NaN            NaN              NaN            NaN                  NaN

[29 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: Well that is pretty much perfect!  Thankyou so much!